# Codeigniter - Add data to the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying add data to the database useing CodeIgniter framework. DB method return true, but I have no new data in database.
There is my controller:

```
class Facebook extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            $this->load->model('user_model','user');
            $data = array();
            $data['u_ip'] = $this->input->ip_address();
            $this->user->add_user($data);
        }
    }
}
```

And there is my model:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function add_user($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('users',$data);
        //$res = $this->db->insert('users',$data); (true)
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**
There is my database:
id_users (int 255) AI, key
u_ip (varchar 100)

Comment: Any. I don't know what is it.

Comment: could you show us the table structure? and are you loading DB..?

Comment: Are you loading the `database`? Either with `$this->load->database();` or through `autoload.php`?

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Comment: What does `$data` look like?

Comment: @BeatAlex $data = array(); $data['u_ip'] = $this->input->ip_address();

Comment: Try `$this->db->insert('users', $data[0]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not mentioning any column names in your query. Try the below code -

```
class User_model extends CI_Model{

public $db;
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);

}

public function add($data)
{
    $data = array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
    );

    $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure your `$data` looks like this:

```
$data = array(
    "u_ip" => $this->input->ip_address(),
);

$this->insert("data", $data);
```

Or if coming from another file, do this:

```
$this->insert("users", $data[0];)
```

Remember to load the dataabse:

```
$this->load->database();
```

This will go within `add_user($data)` eg.

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function add_user($data)
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->insert('users',$data);
        //$res = $this->db->insert('users',$data); (true)
    }
}
```

However, you can have these automatically, if you go to `autoload.php`, you can do this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

And for your model:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('logic');
```

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Answer (score 0):

$this->input->is_ajax_request()

is this posted via a form ? if so it should be $this->input->post('is_ajax_request');
is_ajax_request  being the name of the input your posting,

If its another function within the controller you need to do  $this->is_ajax_request();

Comment: There is posting using **jQuery AJAX**